# How to start a css animation from current position

Tags: css, animation

I would like to start the animation (the first time) from the current position.
the openAnimation goes from the point A to point B and the closeAnimation goes from the point B to the point A.
So, at page loading, the animation is suppose to be in the point B.
but when for the first time I change the class, the div starts from the point A.

```
@-webkit-keyframes openAnimation
  0%
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px)
  100%
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px)

@-webkit-keyframes closeAnimation
  0%
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px)
  100%
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px)
```

in the .open class

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%
-webkit-animation: openAnimation 1s both ease-in
```

in the .close class

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%
-webkit-animation: closeAnimation 1s both ease-in
```

what can I do for don't see the animation the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put this up on jsfiddle.  Chrome/Safari only until you add more vendor prefixes or opt to go with a prefixfree.js or other option.

```
.open {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: openAnimation 1s both ease-in;
}
.close {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: closeAnimation 1s both ease-in;
}
@-webkit-keyframes openAnimation {
      0% {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
      }
      100% {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
      }
}
@-webkit-keyframes closeAnimation {
      0% {
        -webkit-transorm: translateX(300px);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
      }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LtJLc/

Comment: yes man, i'm using only -webkit just for test it on chrome.
thanks for put it on jsfiddle. as you can see from the black square start from the right if we add the close class.
how can I do to force it to start from the current position?

Comment: i mean, if you start with the
    <div class="box"></div>
the square is on the left.
and if you added the class "close" the animation start from the right. how can i do to force it to start from the current point (left) and go to (in this case just stay) on the left?

Comment: Just remove "close" from the box div.  http://jsfiddle.net/LtJLc/1/.  I just added it when I set it up quick

Comment: maybe I didn't explain right :) exactly after add manually the class "close" and click on "RUN", the square box starts from the right and it goes to left. what I would like is that it doesn't start to the right. and just stay there, because it's already in the final position. do you know what I mean?

Comment: Ok, so you want your ending position to be to the right essentially reversed?  If I understood that right, maybe just reverse the .open/.close CSS classes. http://jsfiddle.net/LtJLc/3/.  May have to tweak the 'click' style order too.

Comment: thanks man, yesterday I was really stuck... with this simple condition (hasClass), it's simple to handle...

Comment: Dude, this was a year ago. Did you ever figure out what the key to start another animation from a previous position?

Answer (score 11):

You probably want `transition`, not `animation`. For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/g9dn1a09/

Basically you want following CSS:

```
.box {
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.close {
    transform: translateX(300px);
}

.open {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

Note that you want `transition` defined with a selector that is always applied. If you change property `transition` using `.close` or `.open` class selectors in the middle of the transition (animation) it will look bad.